# Wordpress keeps giving me the wrong permalink

Tags: permalinks, urls

Permalink: http://www.ccdalink.com/team_member/rf-johnson/

is the name of the  permalink

But after I exit and save changes.

Another team_member's page and picture show up in place, and I only have the option to click onto

permalink http://www.ccdalink.com/team_member/Chavez-Raul/

With
 Chavez's picture.

I even set the featured image to RF Johnson's but Chavez's name and picture/permalink keep showing up in place.

What is the issue?

This is a serious issue as I'm assigned with the task of keeping this website updated, but something seems to not be working right.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I'm not quite sure you're talking about.

Comment: Your install has been customized to do that and I'm not sure how to guess at how. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Sure, I am using custompress in order to create the page.
I don't know how custompress would be set up to do this.
I cannot guess how either as I am not the person who set up the website, I'm just being paid for its upkeep. 

There is a custompress update available that keeps linking me to buying wpmu dashboard which is not an option as I have not  been given funds to spend on another program, and I can't afford to spend my own money on the program as I need my money to live.